# Read xml from a path

Tags: c++, xml, com

I have a c++ com code to read the xml from the path where my application resides.But when i try to pick the xml from different path, the code gives compile error.
        HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXMLDom;
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXSLDoc;
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXMLOut;

// Load the XML file. 
pXMLDom.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);


pXMLDom->async = VARIANT_FALSE; // The default is true. 
pXMLDom->validateOnParse = VARIANT_FALSE;
pXMLDom->resolveExternals = VARIANT_FALSE;

pXMLDom->load(L"xmlinputfile.xml");
```

But when i change the last line to pXMLDom->load(L"C:\temp\xmlinputfile.xml");
I get the error. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score -1):

I forgot, i think it needs an escape sequence :)

Comment: Yes, change your path separators in your strings from '\' to '\\'.